# Really basic mySQL Query - replace values

Tags: mysql

This must be really simple:

On mySQL -

UPDATE exp_channel_data

Where entry_id is between 10169 and 10860

If custom_field is value 18

REPLACE with 17

Any ideas?  I'm really struggling with the little knowledge I have!

Comment: UPDATE exp_channel_data SET custom_field=17 WHERE entry_id BETWEEN 10169 and 10860 AND custom_field=18  ???

Comment: @Yzmir Ramirez: Make it an answer instead of a comment and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Rise your knowledge: Get [this book](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0672328631), this is a good start point. Also, check [this tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/mysql/) with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data
SET    custom_field = 17
WHERE  custom_field = 18
AND    entry_id BETWEEN 10169 AND 10860
```

I actually don't remember for sure whether BETWEEN is supported; if not:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data
SET    custom_field = 17
WHERE  custom_field = 18
AND    entry_id >= 10169
AND    entry_id <= 10860
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data 
SET custom_field = 17 
WHERE custom_field = 18 AND entry_id > 10169 AND entry_id < 10860
```

If you want to include 10169 and 10860 use a BETWEEN statement.

The BETWEEN operator functions as 'greater than or equal to' [NUMBER] AND 'less than or equal to' [NUMBER].

BETWEEN example:

```
UPDATE exp_channel_data 
SET custom_field = 17 
WHERE custom_field = 18 AND entry_id BETWEEN 10169 AND 10860
```